# ¿Qué es multi threading?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Mientras aprendía cosas acerca del event loop en Node.js escuche la definición de ''multi threading'' y la verdad no se que a que se refieran con eso o que signifique. Si alguien pudiera explicarme lo apreciaría mucho. De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para decirlo de forma sencilla, un thread es la unidad básica de ejecución: Cuando un programa se ejecuta con al menos un thread (también llamado "hilo de ejecución") se puede decir que es "single thread".

Un programa single thread no está realizado trabajos en paralelo/concurretes. Una forma para realizar varias tareas al mismo tiempo (en paralelo, de forma concurrente) es desde el programa generar nuevos threads, por ejemplo las instrucciones new Thread() de java crean nuevos hilos de ejecución (threads) que se ejecutarán "en paralelo" entonces tenemos un entorno "multi thread" donde además del hilo de ejecución del programa principal, están corriendo los thread hijos lanzados por este.

En el caso de los servidores web, tradicionalmente levantaban un nuevo thread para atender a una nuevo requerimiento del usuario, si habían miles de requerimientos de usuario, en el servidor creaba miles de threads atendiendo a esos requerimientos.

Administrar tantos thread no es gratuito para el servidor, los thread tiene sus ciclos de vida, manejo de memoria, temas de sincronización, etc. Además, dentro de un thread, el ciclo de ejecución es "bloqueante" (tiene que terminar de ejecutarse una instrucción para pasar a la siguiente)

Con la aparición de NodeJS se busca un modelo de servicio más eficiente basado en el Event Loop con un único thread para atender todos los requerimientos de los usuarios. Para tener una ejecución "no bloqueante" la operaciones "costosas" como por ejemplo los accesos de entrada/salida son registradas junto con una función de callback a la cual el servidor debería invocar cuando la operación de entrada y salida haya finalizado.

Gracias a esta estrategia se ganan al menos dos cosas respeto a los servidores web multi-thread: 
a) Se aprovecha el tiempo entre la operación de E/S y el callback para que el event loop pueda seguir atendiendo peticiones de usuarios.
b) Al tener un simple thread atendiendo a todas las peticiones de usuario la utilización de recursos después del setup es constante. (no se gastan recursos para crear/destruir/sincornizar threads)

Esa una respuesta bastante superficial, espero que igual ayude.

Comment: De hecho, Node.js se puede decir que es multithread ya que desechó libev por libuv. siendo este último multithread (por defecto 4).

Answer (score 6):

Antes de *definir* el *multithread*, veamos un poco lo que es un programa.

Un programa es un conjunto de datos y funciones; ni mas ni menos. En la mayoría de lenguajes, los datos son accedidos mediante variables.

Una variable, a su vez, puede ser *global* (se puede acceder a ella desde cualquier punto del programa), o *local* (solo se puede acceder a ella desde la función en la que se definió).

Un *thread* o hilo de ejecución puede considerarse un *punto concreto* de ejecución de un programa. En un momento dado, un *thread* solo puede estar ejecutando una determinada instrucción de código; desde ese punto concreto, podemos acceder a todas las variables globales, pero solo a las variables locales de la función en la que nos encontremos.

Ademas, un *thread* tiene asociado otra información extra: la pila de llamadas actual (la información de las funciones llamantes), junto a los argumentos empleados.

Una aplicación *single thread*, tal y como es Nodejs, solo tiene un *thread*; solo existe un punto de ejecución en un momento dado.

Una aplicación *multi thread*, por su parte, tiene **mas de un punto de ejecución** en un momento dado. Sigue teniendo un único conjunto de variables globales, **pero** tiene mas de una función en ejecución **simultaneamente**, y cada punto de ejecución tiene su propia información de las funciones llamantes, su propio conjunto de argumentos, y su propio grupo de variables locales.

Si ejecutamos una aplicación *multi thread* en una máquina **con mas de 1 CPU**, el rendimiento de dicha aplicación será *superior* a una aplicación de un solo *thread*; cada hilo puede ser ejecutado en una CPU, por lo que podrá ejecutar mas de una tarea a la vez.

Si solo tenemos 1 CPU, esta reparte su tiempo entre todos los hilos de todas los programas en ejecución, por lo que no obtendremos ventaja del uso de varios hilos.

El principal inconveniente de las aplicaciones con múltiples hilos, es mantener el orden en el acceso a los *recursos compartidos* (tales como las variables globales). Centrandonos en estas, pueden ser accedidas desde todos los hilos (a diferencia de las locales). ¿ Que pasa si un hilo cambia una variable global, mientras otro hilo la está leyendo o escribiendo a su vez ? Puedes consultar el clásico [Problema de la cena de los filósofos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_de_la_cena_de_los_fil%C3%B3sofos).

No existe un método para decidir si un programa será *mejor* usando uno o varios hilos. Casi todos los problemas puede ser enfocados desde cualquiera de los dos métodos. Con varios hilos, *en teoría*, se obtendrá mejor rendimiento; con un hilo, mayor simplicidad y facilidad de trabajo.

Del mismo modo, un programa **mal diseñado** que use varios hilos, puede ser **mas lento** que otro con un solo hilo. Y, para determinadas tareas (que puedan ser divididas en bloques de trabajo, sin depender unos bloques de otros), el uso de varios hilos proporciona un rendimiento *muy superior*.

Answer (score 0):

Una aplicación multihilo(multi threading) es una apliación que tiene varios subprogramas ejecutantdose de forma independiente y simultanea.

En Node.js, sólo hay un hilo de ejecución de JavaScript.

Aqui explica mejor como funciona
https://bytearcher.com/articles/why-in-nodejs-lot-of-asynchronous-operations/